# knockout data-bind with $index poses problems

Tags: knockout.js

Concider a jQuery Mobile "list" containing a radio button and a label for it.

```
<!-- ko foreach: $data.answers -->
<input type="radio" name="radio-choice" data-bind="attr: { id: [...] }" />
<label data-bind="attr:{ for: [...] }">Label</label>
<!-- /ko -->
```

In order to work, the **for** attribute of the label needs to be the same as the **id** of the  input.

```
REPLACEMENT FOR [...]            RESULTS IN
$index                           ok
'radio-nr-'+$index               fails
$root.testFunction(1)            ok
$root.testFunction($index)       fails
'radio-nr-'.concat(1)            ok
'radio-nr-'.concat($index)       fails
```

where

```
function testFunction(a) {  return "radio-nr-"+a; };
```

Why do all my attempts of concatenating the $index fail?

Thanks!

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302338/knockout-is-not-evaluating-an-expression-when-using-index-in-a-binding

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [$index documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html):

> Unlike the other binding context properties, $index is an observable

So you need to write `$index()` (note the parenthesis) in your binding:

```
<!-- ko foreach: $data.answers -->
<input type="radio" name="radio-choice" 
                    data-bind="attr: { id: 'radio-nr-' + $index()  }" />
<label data-bind="attr:{ for: 'radio-nr-' + $index() }">Label</label>
<!-- /ko -->
```

A working sample in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/85LAv/1/)