# $index+1 in Knockout foreach binding

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I need to display `$index+1` in a table.

If I just use the `$index` all the elements will start from 0, I need to start at 1.

Here's the documentation of knockout: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html

In there you can find this example:

```
<h4>People</h4>
<ul data-bind="foreach: people">
    <li>
        Name at position <span data-bind="text: $index"> </span>:
        <span data-bind="text: name"> </span>
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removePerson">Remove</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<button data-bind="click: addPerson">Add</button>
```

So it will display the following:

People

> Name at position 0: Bert Remove
>
> Name at position 1: Charles Remove
>
> Name at position 2: Denise Remove

I really need this to be just for display purposes.

> Name at position 1: Bert Remove
>
> Name at position 2: Charles Remove
>
> Name at position 3: Denise Remove

I tried this without success  `<span data-bind="text: ($index + 1)"> </span>`

Comment: Try $index() + 1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Knockout is not evaluating an expression when using $index in a binding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302338/knockout-is-not-evaluating-an-expression-when-using-index-in-a-binding)

Answer (score 134, accepted):

$index is an observable. 
So you need to use it this way :

```
<span data-bind="text: ($index() + 1)"> </span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here:
[Knockout is not evaluating an expression when using $index in a binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302338/knockout-is-not-evaluating-an-expression-when-using-index-in-a-binding?rq=1)

In order to use it `<span data-bind="text: $index() + 1"></span>`