# Adding index based conditional attribute in foreach loop

Tags: knockout.js

In case I do:

```
data-bind="attr: {'id': $index}"
```

than IDs are 0, 1, 2... but if I do:

```
data-bind="attr: {'id': $index>0 ? 'choice'+$index : 'choice'}"
```

than ID is always 'choice', what do I do wrong?

It is Knockout v3.4.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [knockout.js using $index with if binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318441/knockout-js-using-index-with-if-binding), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302338/knockout-is-not-evaluating-an-expression-when-using-index-in-a-binding, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734415/index1-in-knockout-foreach-binding

Comment: It is a duplicate, but from my perspective didn't know what to search for, thought the condition syntax could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

`$index` is actually an observable.  In a simple binding, knockout will handle it automatically.  In a more complex expression, it doesn't, you need to manually call it:

```
data-bind="attr: {'id': $index()>0 ? 'choice'+$index() : 'choice'}"
```

They all end up with just `'choice'`, because `$index>0` will always evaluate to `false`, since it's comparing the text representation of the `$index` observable function with 0.  This function starts with `f` and `"f" > 0` is `false`.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense and it works. But I have never found docs about 'simple' and 'complex' binding, always had problems with that :(

Comment: @skobaljic Just think of anything other than an observable by itself (as per your first example) as "complex".

Comment: I get it, no problems, but never find explanation in docs, was something I had to figure myself. Is there any docs about it? Something that says: If you bind observable only, than you need no brackets?